# Will Form runat="server" submit regular form elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using a `form runat="server"` in a main aspx page.  This page calls user controls.  If a user control has non server side form elements, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="txtlastname">
```

should those still show up in `this.Request.Form`?  I don't see them there.

Comment: They certainly should be in the form collection.

Comment: @Oded: Are you definitely maybe sure about that? ;p

Comment: From what I understand elements not marked with runat="server" are in the posted back form, but you can't get at them using FindControl(). How are you trying to get the values back on the server side?

Comment: @AndrewWalters - OP indicated - `Request.Form`

Comment: What happens when you add an `id` attribute?

Comment: @leppie - Definitely maybe.

Comment: Going to make simple sample project :-)

Comment: Dont tag with `c#-4.0`. There is nothing c#-4.0 about this.

Comment: uh...if c# 4 presents a solution, why leave it out?

Comment: @4thSpace Because C# 4.0 doesn't present a solution over any other version of C#?

Comment: @Rudi, I don't know - does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is available in the Request.Form object

`? Request.Form["lastname"]
"this is the txt box"`

Comment: Just verified with sample project, you're too quick :-)

Comment: I just created a test web app and see the same behavior - form elements not showing in Request.Form.AllKeys.  Can you upload your project?

Comment: Either is fine by me. Not sure how stackoverflow prefers it.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/cd6b6kn - key files are Default.aspx and MyControl.ascx most everything else is boilerplate default project stuff.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't open the project because it said it was missing web components and wanted me to install them.  You have any idea what those are?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  Just a stock WebForms projects in VS2012 w/ Update 1

Comment: Ah, I'm still on vs2010 :)